# Definition of metabolic syndrome, metabolic diseases, and metabolic disorders

Tags: diabetes, metabolism, hypertension, obesity

I found that these terms are frequently used interchangeably, especially when browsing the internet. However, I wonder if there is any (subtle) difference between them.

My current understanding is:

1. Metabolic syndromes: is a term describing obesity, hypertension,
   glucose intolerance, and/ or dyslipidemia, as mentioned [here](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/metabolic-syndrome/symptoms-causes/syc-20351916)
2. Metabolic diseases: is a term describing the actual disease, such as diabetes, stroke, and/ or fatty liver diseases, as mentioned [here](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fphar.2019.00877/full)
3. Metabolic disorder: is a term describing diseases related to metabolism (usually is caused by gene mutation), as mentioned [here](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/inherited-metabolic-disorders/symptoms-causes/syc-20352590)

However, I do find people used them interchangeably, such as [this article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2589936821000736) used metabolic disorders to describe fatty liver diseases.

Please correct me if I am wrong. I would like to know what is the common practice of using these terms in a medical setting. Thanks!

Comment: Your sources are good, and if you read them critically, they in no way contradict each other, nor are the terms used interchangeably. I’m your first example, you misused and/ or. Metabolic syndrome is a specific cluster of disorders, not just one of them. Recommend rereading the sources. Source for 3 is specifically inherited MD. Nowhere is it claimed that all MDs are genetic.